# how to execute Jenkins job after specific time once the previous job completed successfully?

Tags: jenkins

I have two jenkins jobs , I want to trigger the second job after the successful completion of the first job say after 12 hours of time.I need to execute 2 Jenkins jobs after certain time one after the other based on successful completion of first job

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted result?

Comment: Now how many jobs do you have: _two_, or _2_ _after_ _the_ _first_, which would be three?

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of **Quiet Period** and **Post build action** as follows.

Suppose You want to trigger Job B after Job A is done with delay of 1 minute.

Then in your Job B:

1. Go to `General` tab
2. Click on `ADVANCED` button
3. Check `Quiet Period` and enter `60` (= 1 minute)
4. Save

[image: Quiet period]

**In you Job A:**
 1. Go to post build Action
 2. Select Build other project

[image: build other]

3. Enter Job B in `Project to build` and select `Trigger only if build is stable`
4. Save

[image: build]